# Bind scroll event to video element progress using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not sure if this has been answered before but is there a way to bind the `scroll` event to the html5 video `currentTime` element?

Something like:

```
$(window).bind("scroll", vidProgress)
.load(vidProgress);

function vidProgress() {
$('video').currentTime = **viewport scroll progress**;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you define "viewport scroll progress". If you mean scroll progress as in the proportion of scrollable height that has been scrolled past, you can simply divide the scrollTop of the viewport by the scrollable height. Scrollable height, in turn, is simply the difference between the document height and the viewport height.

With this ratio in mind, you can simply multiply it by the duration of the video, accessed using `.duration` property, in order to navigate to the correct timestamp that is to the ratio of the scrollable height of the page.

In my fiddle example, I have set the document height to 500% that of the viewport, and positioned the video fixed relative to the viewport, in order to demonstrate how this works (otherwise the video will scroll out of view).

```
$(function() {
    $(window)
    .on('scroll', vidProgress)
    .load(vidProgress);

    function vidProgress() {
        // Get video properties
        var $v = $('video'),
            duration = $v[0].duration;

        // Get window properties
        var $w = $(window),
            scrollable = $(document).height() - $w.height();

        // Do seeking
        var scrollRatio = $(document).scrollTop()/scrollable;
        if(isNaN(scrollRatio)) scrollRatio = 0;
        $v[0].currentTime = scrollRatio*duration;
    };
});
```

View working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/kr9jmudu/

---

**Note:** If the video is extremely huge, it doesn't make sense to listen to the window's load event. Instead, [listen to the `loadedmetadata` event of the video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/loadedmetadata), so you can already start calculating the ratio.

Comment: That's exactly it! You're a G!

Comment: @pencilsandpixels You're welcome. Glad that it helps! See my edited answer with regards to the `load` event listening :)

Comment: I know its a very old question (and hopefully are still active). How would this set up look if this code is placed inside a friendly iframe hosted somewhere else? Would whit solution still be feasible? I guess the initializing would be looking differently ?